# grep multi text file input and create diferent output each file

Tags: awk, grep, output

i have script that filter several text file using grep and awk in loop, my issue is when create output to each file after filtered,

this my script:

**grep_multi.sh**

```
path=$(find /home/folder/file/source -iname "Tracert*" )

for i in "$path"
do
        grep -E '^%%.*.%%$'\|'IPv4 type' $i | awk '/%%TRACERT:/ {sfx = $0; next} {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7" "$8","sfx}' > filter.result.$i 

done
```

when running the script i got **error** like this:

```
./grep_multi.sh: line 5: filter.result.$i: ambiguous redirect
```

this for **variabel $path**

```
$ find /home/folder/file/source -iname "Tracert*"
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_1.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_2.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_3.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_4.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_5.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_6.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_7.txt
/home/folder/file/source/Tracert_8.txt
```

**tracert_1.txt**

```
O&M    #108
%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded

The result is as follows
------------------------
 Record index  Response number  First response time(ms)  Second response time(ms)  Third response time(ms)  IP type    Peer IP address

 1             3                1                        1                         1                        IPv4 type  10.10.10.10    
 2             3                1                        1                         1                        IPv4 type  10.10.10.10  
 3             0                NULL                     NULL                      NULL                     IPv4 type  Timeout        
 4             0                NULL                     NULL                      NULL                     IPv4 type  Timeout        
 5             3                1                        1                         1                        IPv4 type  10.10.10.10   
 6             3                1                        1                         1                        IPv4 type  10.10.10.10   
 7             3                1                        1                         1                        IPv4 type  10.10.10.10
```

Comment: By quoting the variable `"$path"` you are causing the loop to run once, with `$i` expanding to the whole list of paths. See this somewhat related question [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: ^ what he says. also: that grep expression looks "wrong" (`%%.*.%%` => `%%.*%%`, unsure why we close a quoted block, escape a pipe then open a new quote). Could you give us a sample of what you're trying to extract?

Comment: @SYN i already update my post tracert_1.txt, i want extract every %%TRACERT line fill every "hop", so i can make csv file from that

Comment: allright, makes much more sense now. Should be able to simplify your grep, with: `grep -E '%%.*%%$|IPv4 type' $i ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By quoting the variable `"$path"` you are causing the loop to run once, with `$i` expanding to the whole list of paths. So your redirection ends up something like

```
> filter.result./home/folder/file/source/Tracert_1.txt /home/folder/file/source/Tracert_2.txt ...
```

which is "ambiguous". See this somewhat related question [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

---

You don't really need a shell loop - and you don't need `grep` either. You can select the `IPv4` lines and redirect to a file whose name is derived from the current `FILENAME` all using `awk`:

```
awk '
  /%%TRACERT:/ {sfx = $0; next} 
  /IPv4 type/ {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7" "$8","sfx > "filter.result." FILENAME}
' tracert_*.txt
```

For *local* files, this will produce outputs like:

```
$ head filter.result*
==> filter.result.tracert_1.txt <==
1,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
2,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,IPv4,type Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,IPv4,type Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
5,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
6,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
7,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%

==> filter.result.tracert_2.txt <==
1,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
2,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,IPv4,type Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,IPv4,type Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
5,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
6,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
7,3,1,1,1,IPv4,type 10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="10.10.10.10", MAXHOP=15;%%
```

To use it with `find`, you could do something like:

```
find /home/folder/file/source -iname "Tracert*" -execdir awk '
      /%%TRACERT:/ {sfx = $0; outfile = "filter.result." substr(FILENAME,3); next} 
      /IPv4 type/ {print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7" "$8","sfx > outfile}
' {} +
```

which will place the output files in the same directories where the input files are found. If the files are actually in a single directory, it would be simpler to `cd` there and then use the "local" awk command.

Comment: thank you sir, for `find` can you explain what `substr(FILENAME,3)` and  `{} +` for?

Comment: @ddrackochan `substr(FILENAME,3)` just strips off the `./` relative path that is prepended to the filename by `-execdir` (otherwise the output files would look like `filter.result../Tracert_1.txt`). For the `{} +` syntax please refer to `man find`